# All JavaScript files suddenly showing gibberish content

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of .js files included using `<script>` tags on my page. Everything was working fine until today. Today, the page suddenly started looking horribly broken and when I investigated, I learned that none of the scripts (except for one that I hand-coded personally) were being run. This includes JQuery. When I tried to see the contents of those scripts, I saw gibberish text instead of the actual code. This wasn't the case until last night. What could have possibly caused this without any intervention from anyone and how can I fix it? Hate using the term but this looks like "black magic"!

Update: This is only happening in Opera

The site can be accessed at www.peppyburro.com/sandboxindex

Comment: Might be an issue of character encoding, try changing browser's character encoding http://help.opera.com/Windows/8.54/en/menus.html

Comment: I'm afraid there's no `view` option in my version of Opera. Also checked the `settings` page and found no option to change character encoding. Am using Opera 43 on Win 10.

Comment: Try toggling menu it with Alt key on your keyboard

Comment: The Alt key only serves to show the drop down menu which I can already see. It's the "view" option that's missing.